# On expanding $\frac{1}{(1-\alpha z)(1-\beta z)(1-\gamma z)\cdots}$ into a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Now we will consider this expression
> $$\frac{1}{(1-\alpha z)(1-\beta z)(1-\gamma z)\cdots}$$
> which actually expanded out by division provides this series:
> $$1+Az+Bz^2+Cz^3+\cdots$$
> and it is evident that that the coefficients $A,B,C$ etc. are composed in the following manner from the numbers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ etc., so that there shall be
> $$A=\text{sum of the individual terms,}$$
> $$B=\text{sum of the factors two at a time,}$$
> $$C=\text{sum of the factors three at a time,}$$
> $$\text{etc.}$$
> with the same factors not excluded.
> (Euler, Introductio in analysin infinitorum)

How is that evident? I tried using the formula for division of power series, namely
$$\frac{1}{\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n z^n}=\sum_{n\ge 0}b_n z^n$$
where
$$b_0=\frac{1}{a_0},\,b_n=-\frac{1}{a_0}\sum_{1\le k\le n}a_k b_{n-k}$$
and the multinomial theorem,
$$(x_1 + x_2  + \cdots + x_m)^n
 = \sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_m=n; \ k_1, k_2, \cdots, k_m \geq 0}\frac{n!}{k_1!\, k_2! \cdots k_m!}\prod_{1\le t\le m} x_t^{k_t},$$
but didn't come close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand in geometric series, and count how many terms give an $x^k$ coefficient. That occurs when you take $k$ products (with multiplicity) of an $x$-coefficient and set all other factors equal to $1$. This is similar to the multinomial theorem. Their language is quite loose, but notice that the multinomial theorem gives $k_1+k_2+\cdots=n$ so the product $\prod_{1\le t\le m}x_t^{k_t}$ indeed is a product of '$n$ [terms] at a time'. You want to consider, e.g.: $$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\alpha^nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\beta^nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\gamma^nx^n\right)=1+(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)x\\+(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\alpha\gamma)x^2+\cdots$$Since the only way to make $x$ in a product is to have one $x$-term and two constant terms, with resulting coefficient $\alpha$ or $\beta$ or $\gamma$, depending on the choice of $x$-term. And so on.